How can I post array of objects like example
I have a problem with calling an API with Laravel.
I wont to call an api with a request like this (this is an example of json request):
{
   "costCenterCode":"CDC-00070964",
   "paperless":"false",
   "shipmentDate":"2020-11-26T08:02:20.986+0000",
   "waybills":[
      {
         "clientReferenceId":"12312312341",
         "printFormat":"A4",
         "product":"APT000901",
         "data":{
            "declared":[
               {
                  "weight":"10",
                  "height":"10",
                  "length":"30",
                  "width":"25"
               }
            ],
         }
      }
   ]
}

This is my post code:
$insert = Http::withHeaders([
        'POSTE_clientID' => '4815fd18-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-d1a1edbd7a12',
        'Authorization' => $auth,
    ])
    ->post('https://apiw.gp.posteitaliane.it/gp/internet/postalandlogistics/parcel/waybill', [
        "costCenterCode" => "CDC-00051975",
        "paperless" => "false",
        "shipmentDate" => "2024-06-29T08=>02=>20.986+0000",
        "waybills" => [
            "clientReferenceId" => "1404343485",
            "printFormat" => "A4",
            "product" => "APT000901",
            "data" => [
                "declared" => [
                    "weight" => "0",
                    "height" => "44",
                    "length" => "30",
                    "width" => "25"
                ],
            ]
        ]
    ])
    ->json();

What am I doing wrong? There is an array of object, I don't know.
Can you help me?

Run json_encode() on your array and compare expected and actual. If it's still not clear, reduce the amout of data further. This looks like a simple and obvious typo to me, which surely would have been resolved by extracting a [mcve]. Please, as a new user here, also take the [tour] and read [ask].

There are two things that I can see going wrong.

The array is not properly formatted.

You want to pass the following json
...
"waybills": [
    {
        "clientReferenceId":"12312312341",
        "printFormat":"A4",
        "product":"APT000901",
        "data": {
            "declared": [
                {
                    "weight":"10",
                    "height":"10",
                    "length":"30",
                    "width":"25"
                }
            ],
        }
    }
],
...

but the php array
...
"waybills" => [
    "clientReferenceId" => "1404343485",
    "printFormat" => "A4",
    "product" => "APT000901",
    "data" => [
        "declared" => [
            "weight" => "0",
            "height" => "44",
            "length" => "30",
            "width" => "25"
        ],
    ]
],
...

will generate
...
"waybills": {
    "clientReferenceId":"12312312341",
    "printFormat":"A4",
    "product":"APT000901",
    "data": {
        "declared": [
            {
                "weight":"10",
                "height":"10",
                "length":"30",
                "width":"25"
            }
        ],
    }
}
...

instead.
To fix this, simply change that part by
...
"waybills" => [
    [
        "clientReferenceId" => "1404343485",
        "printFormat" => "A4",
        "product" => "APT000901",
        "data" => [
            "declared" => [
                "weight" => "0",
                "height" => "44",
                "length" => "30",
                "width" => "25"
            ],
        ]
    ]
]
...


You say you are calling an API but you're not specifying any json headers in the request.

To fix that, you can use the Http facade's asJson method.
$insert = Http::asJson()
    ->withHeaders([
        'POSTE_clientID' => '4815fd18-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-d1a1edbd7a12',
        'Authorization' => $auth,
    ])
    ->post('https://apiw.gp.posteitaliane.it/gp/internet/postalandlogistics/parcel/waybill', [
        "costCenterCode" => "CDC-00051975",
        "paperless" => "false",
        "shipmentDate" => "2024-06-29T08=>02=>20.986+0000",
        "waybills" => [
            [
                "clientReferenceId" => "1404343485",
                "printFormat" => "A4",
                "product" => "APT000901",
                "data" => [
                    "declared" => [
                        "weight" => "0",
                        "height" => "44",
                        "length" => "30",
                        "width" => "25"
                    ],
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ])
    ->json();

